# Definite Integration

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the mean value of voltage $$V=220 \sin(140\pi t)$$
over the range t = 0 to t = 3.6ms.

I have came up with this answer. But it doesn't seen correct as it is 0. And I wouldn't of thought the mean range is 0.

$$\frac{1}{3.6} \int_0^{3.6} 220 \sin(140 \pi t) \, dt$$

\begin{align*}
 &= \frac{220}{3.6} \int_0^{140\cdot \pi \cdot 3.6} \frac{\sin u}{140 \pi} \, du \\
&= \frac{220}{140(3.6)\pi} \left[ {-\cos u} \right]_0^{140(3.6)\pi} \\
&= \frac{220}{504 \pi} \left[ -\cos (504\pi) + \cos(0) \right] \\
&= \frac{220}{504\pi} \cdot(0) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Can anyone tell me if I have done this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: The mean voltage is indeed zero.  If you want the mean power or the RMS voltage, that's another story.

Comment: I need to find the mean value of the voltage. So I guess it must be zero. It just didn't seem right to be 0. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: why doesn't that seem right?  The voltage is positive "just as often" as it is negative.

Comment: I'm new to this and learning it. So I just didn't think it would be zero.

Comment: In your formula for $V$, time should be expressed in seconds or in milliseconds?

Comment: it just says ms. So would that be milliseconds?

Comment: If, in the formula, $t$ is seconds, the integration must go to $3.6$ milliseconds.

Comment: So the formula above in incorrect?